# dynamic mysql for record counts

Tags: mysql

I am not an expert in MYSQL and mainly develop in tsql but I am needing to write a dynamic piece of code that will give me the count of records per table based on a specific date range.  The code below gives me row counts for all my tables in my database but I have a second table that has a record for each table and says whether it has a create_date field that I can query.  What I want to do is alter my code to look at the secondary table and use the created_date field if available to build the select statement.  The plan is to pass in a date at the top of the procedure and use that date to calculate the counts only where the required field is available, if its not available a total record count will be shown.

Hope that has made some sense and any pointers would be much appreciated as, as I said before MYSQL isn't my thing but I would like to learn.

Thanks P

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = (1000000);
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet = (50*1024*1024);

select
  -- Sort the tables by count
  concat( 
    'select * from (',
    -- Aggregate rows into a single string connected by unions
    group_concat(
      -- Build a "select count(1) from db.tablename" per table
      concat('select ', 
        quote(db), ' db, ', 
        quote(tablename), ' tablename, '
        'count(1) "rowcount" ',
       'from ', db, '.', tablename) 
      separator ' union ')
    , ') t ')
into @sql 
from (
  select 
    table_schema db,
    table_name tablename
  from information_schema.tables 
  where table_schema not in 
    ('sampledatabase')
) t;

-- Execute @sql
prepare s from @sql; execute s; deallocate prepare s;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL actually has a list of table-columns, you can just look up there if a table has a column `create_date` and add a `where`-condition in this case:

```
set @mydate = '2016-01-01';

select
  -- Sort the tables by count
  concat( 
    'select * from (',
    -- Aggregate rows into a single string connected by unions
    group_concat(
      -- Build a "select count(1) from db.tablename" per table
      concat('select ', 
        quote(db), ' db, ', 
        quote(tablename), ' tablename, ',
        'count(1) rowcount, ',
        has_createddate, ' filtered ',
        'from `', db, '`.`', tablename,'`', 
        -- add "where" when the column is there
        case when has_createddate = 1 then concat(' where create_date ',
        -- your filter condition, e.g.
        ' >= ''', @mydate, '''')
        else '' end
      ) 
      separator ' union ')
    , ') t ')
into @sql 
from (
  select 
    t.table_schema db,
    t.table_name tablename,
    case when not c.COLUMN_NAME is null then 1 else 0 end has_createddate
  from information_schema.tables t
  left join information_schema.COLUMNS c
  on t.table_schema = c.table_schema
  and t.table_name = c.table_name
  and c.column_name = 'create_date'
  where t.table_schema not in ('sampledatabase')
) t;
```

You can use your own table with the same logic. If the field in your lookuptable contains a column name that you want to filter with (instead of the constant `create_date`), you can use that column in the `concat`, e.g.

```
... 
case when not filtercol is null then concat(' where `', filtercol, '`',  ' >= ''',
...
```

Comment: Hi Solarflare, that is brilliant exactly what I was looking for and you learn something new every day.